# How do I add items to an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, firebug, getjson

```
var list = [];
$.getJSON("json.js", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.text);
        list.push(item.text);
    });
});
console.log(list.length);
```

`list.length` always returns 0.  I've browsed the JSON in firebug and it's well formed and everything looks fine.  I just can't seem to add an item to the array what am I missing?

Comment: This seems right. Does the `$.each` loop print items to the log, but doesn't add them to `list`?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Since `$.getJSON` is async, I think your `console.log(list.length);` code is firing before your array has been populated. To correct this put your `console.log` statement inside your callback:

```
var list = new Array();
$.getJSON("json.js", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.text);
        list.push(item.text);
    });
    console.log(list.length);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you..

```
var list = [];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').click(function () {
            var oRows = $('#MainContent_Table1 tr').length;
            $('#MainContent_Table1 tr').each(function (index) {
                list.push(this.cells[0].innerHTML);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making an ajax request which is asynchronous therefore your console log of the list length occurs before the ajax request has completed.

The only way of achieving what you want is changing the ajax call to be synchronous. You can do this by using the .ajax and passing in asynch : false however this is not recommended as it locks the UI up until the call has returned, if it fails to return the user has to crash out of the browser.